# Magnific Popup with Wordpress Galleries

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, magnific-popup

I am building a Wordpress theme and I want to add Magnific Popup - dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

I managed to get it working with single images with the following code in my functions.php file:

```
/**
* Add title back to images
*/
function pexeto_add_title_to_attachment( $markup, $id ){
    $att = get_post( $id );
    return str_replace('<a ', '<a title="'.$att->post_title.'" ', $markup);
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'pexeto_add_title_to_attachment', 10, 5);

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_magnificpopup_styles');
function enqueue_magnificpopup_styles() {
    wp_register_style('magnific_popup_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/magnific-popup.css', array('style.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('magnific_popup_style');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_magnificpopup_scripts');
function enqueue_magnificpopup_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('magnific_popup_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('magnific_popup_script');
    wp_register_script('magnific_init_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.magnific-popup-init.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('magnific_init_script');
}
```

However it says 'Image could not be loaded' when I click an image in a Wordpress Gallery as it obviously has different HTML markup.  Has anyone found a way to make this work with Wordpress Galleries?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work if the images are linked to "image file". Put this in a javascript file and enqueue the file after jQuery is ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".gallery-icon a").magnificPopup();
    });
```

Comment: I have no idea how to impliment this

Comment: You have to put this in a javascript file.

Comment: It just gives me two errors now, I tried this also and it links to a 404 page.

$('.gallery .gallery-item .gallery-icon a').each(function() {
        $(this).magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            gallery: {enabled: true}
            });
        });
    });

Comment: It's just linking to a 404 page now, the url is appearing as wordpress/?attachment_id=54

Comment: I know why now, the anchor tag is linking to a attachment page and not the image.